# Formatting a variable as a string

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to create a Python program that will query a URL and produce a JSON file. I need to pass an argument in the end of the URL which comes from the SQL query.

I have imported the `requests` library.

I get an error message 'TypeError: float argument required, not str' when I am trying to pass argument in the URL.

There is only one column of result produced from the query:

```
id   
2
3
4
```

Below is what I came up with:

```
import MySQLdb
import requests

con=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="test", passwd="test", db ="mfg")
cur = con.cursor()
select=("select id from tblMfg")

cur.execute(select)
result=cur.fetchall()
for i in result:
    col =i[0]
    col1=str(col)
    url = 'http://appl.xyz.net:8080/app/content/pq/doQuery?solution=nd&path=&file=Test.nd&dataAccessId=1&paramid=%d' % col1
    user = 'abc'
    password ='testgo'
    data = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
    json_data=data.json()
    print json_data
```

Comment: … Python also tells you *where* the error is (and by inference that it has nothing to do with URLs or argument passing).

Comment: You actually had to go out of you way to get this error, first using `%d` instead of `%s` to mean "I absolutely positively want this to work only with numbers, not strings", then doing `col1=str(col)` to say "I absolutely positively want this to be a string, not a number". And then, when Python says "Hey, that string isn't a number", you don't understand it? (Maybe they both _actually_ mean "I copied and pasted this line of code without understanding it at all"?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave [creating parameters](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) to the `requests` framework instead:

```
params = {'solution': 'nd', 'path': '', 'file': 'Test.nd', 'dataAccessId': '1',
          'paramid': str(col[0])}
url = 'http://appl.xyz.net:8080/app/content/pq/doQuery'
user = 'abc'
password ='testgo'
data = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password), params=params)
```

Comment: It says: TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__'. Could you show the full code?

Comment: Still no luck: TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__'. We are getting integer values from table and passing into the url

Comment: @Rio: I tested with some variations and `params` can have integer and long values just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error message  'TypeError: float argument required, not str' also occurs when you try to format a string containing an (accidental) naked percent sign.
Example:

```
>>> print "fail 100% for serverid|%s| " % ("a")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: float argument required, not str
>>>
```

The "f" after the "100% " is interpreted as asking for a floating point argument, whereas it was simply my smudgefingers leaving off the second percent sign.

```
>>> print "fail 100%% for serverid|%s| " % ("a")
fail 100% for serverid|a|
>>>
```

works fine.  If the word following the "100% " begins with d or o or s, you get slightly different error messages.

I was unlucky enough to have this happen several call layers inside a 2-nested try-except, so the error showed up a mile away from the line that caused it.

Answer (score -1):

```
print ("float_value : %f , digit_value : %d , string_value : %s"  % (3.4, 5, 'somestring'))
float_value : 3.400000 , digit_value : 5 , string_value : somestring
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation?